# Pattern Match on String Column

Tags: azure-log-analytics

In many functional programming languages there is a way to do pattern matching, like F# has `match expression with`.

In my use case, I'd like to match a string to a set of strings/regexes and returning a value(a string):

```
// path:string
iif(path == '/', 'home',
iif(path == '/search', 'search',
iif(path == '/*/*/*-for-sale-*', 'product',
'other',
)))
```

The `iif` syntax is really ugly though. Is there a more concise way to find a string match and return a value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a relatively new syntax for [case()](https://docs.loganalytics.io/docs/Language-Reference/Scalar-functions/case()):

```
range Size from 1 to 15 step 2
| extend bucket = case(Size <= 3, "Small", 
                       Size <= 10, "Medium", 
                       "Large")
```